# Javascript Serializer in asp.net mvc produces malformed Json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, javascriptserializer

I am in asp.net mvc 3 with razor. The model is of type `IList<PipeLineView>`. The definition of `PipeLineView` is

```
public class PipeLineView
    {
        public string Stage { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int LevelNo { get; set; }
    }
```

In the view I am doing something like

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = serializer.Serialize(Model);
```

and In  the javascript I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data =JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(data));
</script>
```

When I load the page in firefox, I get the following js error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]   

...":5,"LevelNo":1},{"Stage":"Level2","Amount":0.000,"Color":"Red","Count":0,"Level...
```

What could be the problem here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.parse expects a JSON string so you need to string quote the argument so add `''` around the `@Html.Raw(data)`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(data)');
</script>
```

But in your case you don't need to parse you can just write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = @Html.Raw(data);
</script>
```